# ListBox inside ListBox virtualization

Tags: wpf, xaml, virtualization

ListBox has child listbox as an item. Virtualization works great on parent listBox however, requirement is to activate virtualization on child listbox + child listbox should not have scrollbar. is it possible?

Comment: Where is your MCVE? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: New to stack overflow, now i know what is MCVE thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Height` or `MaxHeight` property of the inner `ListBox` and also the `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` attached property of you want to disable the scrollbar. The following example uses UI virtualization in both `ListBoxes`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var outer = Resources["outer"] as CollectionViewSource;
        outer.Source = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);

        var inner = Resources["inner"] as CollectionViewSource;
        inner.Source = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="outer" />
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="inner" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource outer}}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource inner}}" 
                             MaxHeight="100" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```